# Ansible: How to remove & register a VM from VCenter?

Tags: ansible, vmware, vcenter

I need to do a vmotion and I would need:

- Unregister machine from VMWare VCenter.
- Register that machine into another cluster.

Is it possible to do with an Ansible module?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the same cluster, have you tried : 
[vmware_vmotion – Move a virtual machine using vMotion, and/or its vmdks using storage vMotion](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/vmware_vmotion_module.html) ?

but you're talking about 'another cluster' so i think it won't work  :
as said in [Live Migration of Virtual Machines](https://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere/vmotion.html)

```
VMware vSphere vMotion is a zero downtime live migration of workloads 
from one server to another. This capability is possible across 
vSwitches, Clusters, and even Clouds
```

So you are not doing vMotion by migrating from a cluster to another (you will have down time).

What you want to do is stop vm, download vmdk files from a cluster, upload it to another, and restore a vm with it (but i never did that, i only have one cluster)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, when using vmware_guest, setting a VM state to "absent" will destroy it instead of unregistering it.

Similarly, I don't see any way to add a VM back to the inventory by way of a VMX file.